# The argument type 'AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Object>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object>'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am Trying to build an app. which fetching the user credential data and shows in profile page. the error i am getting is

> **The argument type** **'AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>' can't be**
> **assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot'.**

NEED HELP!

```
child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false)
                  .getUserUid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              return new Column(
                children: [
                  Provider.of<ProfileHelpers>(context, listen: false).headerProfile(context, snapshot)
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
```

I think the error is around the **.headerProfile(context, snapshot)**

below is the code of headerProfile :

```
                GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: constantColors.transperant,
                radius: 60.0,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot['userimage']),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Text(snapshot['username'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 16.0)),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(EvaIcons.email, color: constantColors.greenColor),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:8.0),
                    child: Text(snapshot['useremail'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16.0)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

I think the error is coming from the **snapshot['username']**, **snapshot['userimage']** and **snapshot['useremail']**

NEED HELP!

Comment: did you get the answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `DocumentSnapshot` from the `AsyncSnapshot` returned by the `StreamBuilder`'s `builder` callback.

Do this by calling `.data` on `snapshot`.

Change this:

```dart
.headerProfile(context, snapshot)
```

to this:

```dart
.headerProfile(context, snapshot.data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `snaphot['username']`, `snapshot['userimage']` and `snapshot['useremail']` to this below:

```
snapshot.get('username')
snapshot.get('userimage')
snapshot.get('useremail')
```